# PyAudio Segmentation Fault on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyaudio

I installed PyAudio on my Raspberry Pi without any problems but I'm unable to run any sample test. If I run any of them the app just "pauses" for a while and then it quits with a segmentation fault.

I stripped out the code and found that these 2 lines of code produce the same result:

```
import pyaudio
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
```

Do you know what might be causing this error?

I thought it could be a misconfiguration of the sound card but I tested recording and playing sound from the sound card with:

```
arecord -D plughw:0,0 -f cd test.wav
aplay test.wav
```

and it worked as expected.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you install `pyaudio` by `sudo apt-get install python-pyaudio`

Comment: I first installed it by `sudo python setup.py install` and after I got the segmentation fault I installed it by `sudo apt-get install python-pyaudio`

Comment: Noticed that if I run any of the pyaudio samples with sudo it doesn't exit with the segmentation fault but I don't see any output, the app just holds for a few seconds and then exits without showing any messages.